# How to write test Rspec for class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to RSpec so this really give me a headache. I have a search by keyword or by category in Post model:

```
def self.search(search, category_id)
  if search.strip.empty?
    []
  elsif category_id.empty?
    Post.approved.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase.strip}%")
  else
    @category = Category.find_by('id = ?', category_id.to_i)
    @category.posts.approved.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase.strip}%")
  end
end
```

I know how to write test for easy thing like validations and associations, but I still can not  figure how to write test for this class method. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some test data:

```
let!(:post_1) { Post.create(title: 'some example title') }
let!(:post_2) { Post.create(title: 'another title') }
```

And validate that your search returns the correct records for various search terms, e.g.:

```
expect(Post.search('example')).to contain_exactly(post_1)

expect(Post.search('EXAMPLE')).to contain_exactly(post_1)

expect(Post.search('title')).to contain_exactly(post_1, post_2)

expect(Post.search('foo')).to be_empty
```

(assuming `search` is a method of `Post`)